# Mono Site Failed to map path '/App_WebReferences/.... Error

Tags: asp.net, apache, mono, mod-mono

I have an open source asp.net site that is meant to run under apache/mono.  I have a new version I am all ready to release but it has a problem running under linux.  Everything works great on windows.

The first time I load the page I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException Failed to map path '/App_WebReferences/MythContent/ContentServices.wsdl'

The file is there:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 37K Nov 20  2013 mobilemyth/App_WebReferences/MythContent/ContentServices.wsdl

Refresh the page again and you get:

> System.IO.IOException
>   Sharing violation on path /tmp/www-data-temp-aspnet-0/9e3969b/Resources.frontendsettings.aspx.resources

And that is all you get from them on.  Any ideas?

Comment: :( Still having this problem.

Comment: Solution is here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24457 You can comment relevant line in System.Web

Comment: Interesting.  I'll have to see if that matches.  Sadly this is an open source site I distribute, so my users will still be stuck.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

In Mono, the best solution for this issue is using the `wsdl2` command line and generate the class an put it in the `App_Cod`. So you can use the WebService client in your app.

Sample:

```
$ wsdl2 http://< your url of wsdl >?WSDL
```